# Expected value of a minimum variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to solve the following math problem now.

Let $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n, ...$ be independent random variables with identical uniform distributions on interval $(0,1)$. Let

$N=\min \left\{ n \geq 0: \sum _{i=1}^{n} U_i > \frac{1}{2} \right\}$.

**Find the expected value $\mathbb E \left[N\right]$.**

Could anybody, please, drop a hint how to solve it?

Comment: Can you find the probability mass function? For instance, it is trivial that $\Pr(N=1) = 0.5$. Can you find $\Pr(N=n)$ for $n >1$?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is convolution, but it isn't trivial even for n=2, let alone n convolutions... But I'm not sure it's the right direction

Comment: Yes it is the right direction to use convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge 1$,

$$\mathbb P\left[N > n\right] = \mathbb P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \le \frac12\right] = F_n\left(\frac12\right)$$

where for $0 \le x \le 1$,

\begin{align}
F_n(x) &= \mathbb P\left[\sum_{i=1}^nU_i \le x\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb P\left[\left.\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i \le x - U_n\right|U_n\right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[F_{n-1}\left(x - U_n\right)\right]\\
&= \int_{0}^1 F_{n-1}(x-u)\mathrm d u\\
&= \int_{0}^x F_{n-1}(x-u)\mathrm d u\\
&= \int_{0}^x F_{n-1}(u)\mathrm d u
\end{align}

With $F_1(x) = x$. Now prove by induction that
$$F_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Finally,

$$\mathbb E\left[N\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb P\left[N > n\right] = 1 
+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n n!} = e^{\frac12} = \sqrt{e}$$